# What does 'subregion' mean in Illinois State Report Card data?

Tags: usa, education

In the [Illinois State Report Cards](http://www.isbe.net/assessment/report_card.htm) data for schools, there are fields that refer to 'Subregions'? What are subregions?

Here are a couple of reports cards that use subregions:

http://webprod.isbe.net/ereportcard/publicsite/getReport.aspx?year=2012&code=1501629902054_e.pdf
http://webprod.isbe.net/ereportcard/publicsite/getReport.aspx?year=2012&code=1501629902059_e.pdf

So far, I've only seen subregions defined for Chicago schools.

Comment: Could you link to the exact spreadsheet/PDF that contains the keyword? I could not find 'Subregion' anywhere.

Comment: I can't say for Illinois, but I know that in my county in Maryland, they're fixed areas for planning purposes separate from the representative districts for voting -- because the districts have to change with each census.

Comment: Just for the record: I tried, but my Google Foo was not strong enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these subregions are CPS 'networks':

From http://www.cps.edu/fy13budget/pages/Schoolsandnetworks.aspx

> Networks/Collaboratives District-run schools in CPS are organized into
>   five geographic collaboratives – North/Northwest, West, Southwest,
>   South, and Far South – and then further divided into 19 Networks,
>   which provide administrative support, strategic direction and
>   leadership development to the schools within each Network. There are
>   13 elementary Networks, four high school Networks, one K-12 Network
>   that serves both elementary and high schools, and one alternative
>   Network for alternative schools.

```
Network                                   No. of Schools 
Austin-North Lawndale Elementary Network  32
Burnham Park Elementary Network           36
Englewood-Gresham Elementary Network      33
Fullerton Elementary Network              41
Fulton Elementary Network                 30
Garfield-Humboldt Elementary Network      28
Midway Elementary Network                 36
O'Hare Elementary Network                 42
Pershing Elementary Network               31
Pilsen-Little Village Elementary Network  26
Ravenswood-Ridge Elementary Network       40
Rock Island Elementary Network            29
Skyway Elementary Network                 40
Far South Side K-12 Network               37
North-Northwest Side High School Network  25
South Side High School Network            19
Southwest Side High School Network        19
West Side High School Network             27
Alternative Schools                        6
```